# Netezza 7.2 UDF instantiate method called twice

Tags: netezza

After I register a Netezza UDF, I have a select statement that uses the UDF. I have found that the UDF's instantiate method is called twice for that select statement.  Any idea why?

Sample select stmt:

```
select my_udf(somecolumn, 'some parm info') from evtest;
```

I would think the udf's instantiate would only get called once for this select, but it's called twice, which baffles me.

Thanks

Comment: Strange indeed. I would have expected it to be executed once per SPU and once on the HOST, or only once in total... Are there any difference between calling it with _v_dual and _v_dual_dslice ... they should help you see which of my expectations are true (if any)?

Comment: Due to other technical issues on my end, I'm not going to be able to answer your question Lars.  But what you wrote does give me further food for thought, so thank you for that.

Comment: Sounds like a random page in my diary :) let us know when feasible what your thinking and tinkering allows you to figure out ...

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I've solved the mystery.

I believe that the instantiate method is called during statement preparation, then again is called when actually doing the work of the statement.

My reasoning:
I added a logMsg stmt to my constructor and I see that for each of the two calls, the log messages went to two different log files.  This experimentation was not done with _v_dual, but was done with .

Neither of my logMsg calls went to /nz/kit/log/dbos/dbos.log, which is for user-defined functions that run on the host.

Only ONE of my log messages went to /nz/kit/log/postgres/pg.log, which is  for the functions that operate on the system catalog or at statement preparation time

BOTH of my log messages went to 
/nz/kit/log/sysmgr/sysmgr.log, which is for the functions that run on the SPUs.

This, I think, answers my original question.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me. I suppose a jit statistics could trigger a third invocation from time to time :)